# How I can translate words in Cesium JavaScript Library?

Tags: cesiumjs

How I can translate words in Cesium JS? Its possible? For example, I want translate hint text "View Home" button, search button and etc. There is nothing in the official documentation about translating words into another language. I did not find any configs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example, the hint "view home" can be replaced. Here is the documentation. https://cesium.com/docs/cesiumjs-ref-doc/HomeButtonViewModel.html
See field 'tooltip'.

Comment: Thanks. I solved the problem like this
    
`viewer.homeButton.viewModel.tooltip = 'some text';`